# Get all the selected radio button and check box value created dyamically?

Tags: android, android-edittext, textview, radio-button, checkboxlist

I want to save all the selected answer(checkbox and  radiobutton) and its corresponding question  which is set in dynamic Textview in sqlite db , 
             but the problem is when i am clicking "save button" only last selected 
    radio button value is saved to sqlite , not all selected value and not able to get all selected check box value also .
             Please help me .

```
save= (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
        save.setOnClickListener(this);
        ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout1);

        for (int j = 0; j < Questions.length; j++) {
               tv = new TextView(this);
               tv.setId(j);
            tv.setText(Questions[j].getQuestionNo() + "."
                    + Questions[j].getQuestion());
            ll.addView(tv);

            Answer[] answer = Questions[j].getAnswer();
            if (Questions[j].getMultipleChoice().equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {
                rg = new RadioGroup(this);
                rg.setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
                RadioButton[] rb = new RadioButton[answer.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < answer.length; i++)
                {
                     // add radio buttons
                    rb[i] = new RadioButton(this);
                    rb[i].setText(answer[i].getLabel());
                    int id = Integer.parseInt(j + "" + i);
                    rb[i].setId(id);
                    rg.addView(rb[i]);
                            }
                ll.addView(rg);

            else 
                        {
                            // add checkboxes
                   for (int i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
                    cb = new CheckBox(this);
                    cb.setText(answer[i].getLabel());
                    int id = Integer.parseInt(j + "" + i);
                    cb.setId(id);

                    ll.addView(cb);
                                                            } 
                        } 


}



 public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.save:

                if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() != -1) {
                    int id = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    View radioButton = rg.findViewById(id);
                    int radioId = rg.indexOfChild(radioButton);
                    RadioButton btn = (RadioButton) rg.getChildAt(radioId);
                    String answer = (String) btn.getText();
                    //only last selected radio button value is coming 
                             }

                         // not able to get all the selected checkbox value
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know android.But the issue arise me in struts2.I solved that issue by generating dynamic checkbox like below.

```
<s:iterator value="samplelist">
<input type="checkbox"  value="true" style="margin-top:2px;" name="p_<s:property value='profileId'/>
</s:iterator>
```

so i have found out if it is checked or not in java code by using the for loop

```
for(int i=0;i<samplelist.size();i++)
request.getParameter("P_something");
```